# Javafx conflicts between observers and getstyleclass() listener

Tags: java, css, javafx, observable

I have a problem with a JavaFX application.

I have a class creating a list of buttons in a hbox.
This class extends AnchorPane.

When i click on a button, I change the css class applied to this button, and the previous one so it's normal again.
The problem is to add an observer so my button can be usefull.

As my class is already extending AnchorPane, i can't extends Observable, so I created a new class with static methods. This class is the observed one and notify the observed when a method is called.

Here is the code of the class with the list of buttons :

```
/**
 *
 * @author olivier
 */
public class SpecificElementViewController extends AnchorPane implements Initializable {

  private List<String> elementTypesList;

  @FXML
  private HBox hbox;

  private Button selectedButton = null;

  private SpecificElementListTypes specificElementType;

  public SpecificElementViewController() {
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
  }

  public List<String> getElementTypes() {
    return elementTypesList;
  }

  public void setElementTypes(List<String> elementTypesList, SpecificElementListTypes type) {
    this.specificElementType = type;
    Button button;

    if (elementTypesList != null && !elementTypesList.isEmpty()) {

      for (String s : elementTypesList) {
        button = new Button(s);

        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
          @Override
          public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Pressed button : " + ((Button) event.getSource()).getText());
            if (selectedButton.getStyleClass().contains("selectedNode")) {
              selectedButton.getStyleClass().remove("selectedNode");
            }
            selectedButton = (Button) event.getSource();
            selectedButton.getStyleClass().add("selectedNode");
            SpecificElementViewObservable.handleSpecificElementListClick(specificElementType, selectedButton);
          }
        });
        hbox.getChildren().add(button);
      }
      if (selectedButton == null) {
        selectedButton = (Button) hbox.getChildren().get(0);
        selectedButton.getStyleClass().add("selectedNode");
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is the class of the observable class :

```
public class SpecificElementViewObservable extends Observable {

  private static SpecificElementViewObservable instance;

  public static void handleSpecificElementListClick(SpecificElementListTypes elementType, Button button) {
    SpecificElementViewObservable.getInstance().setChanged();
    SpecificElementViewObservable.getInstance().notifyObservers(new SpecificElementEvent(elementType, button));
  }

  public static SpecificElementViewObservable getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new SpecificElementViewObservable();
    }
    return instance;
  }
}
```

The class observing this one is too big to be added here, I'll just add the addobserver and update method :

```
/**
 *
 * @author olivier
 */
public class MainWindowController extends AnchorPane implements Initializable, Observer {

   @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
     SpecificElementViewObservable.getInstance().addObserver(this);
  }

public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        System.out.println("Receive update");
        if (arg instanceof SpecificElementEvent) {
          SpecificElementEvent event = (SpecificElementEvent) arg;
          System.out.println("Type : " + event.getType().toString());
          System.out.println("Button text : " + event.getButton().getText());
          try {
            handlePlanetMenuClick(null);
          } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error using null mouseEvent : " + ex.getMessage());
          }
        } else {
          System.out.println("Error unknown event");
        }
      }
```

This problem is I can't make my listener work with the css update.
With this code, my listener works, but the css is not applied.
As you can see on the setElementTypes method, the list of buttons is created, with the 1st one considered as "selected". At this moment, the css is applied (the buttons are yellow, except the selectedButton which is red).
When I click on another button, the red one becomes yellow again, but the new selectedButton stays yellow (the value of selectedButton is changed). After that, the CSS is never changed.

If I remove this line :

```
SpecificElementViewObservable.handleSpecificElementListClick(specificElementType, selectedButton);
```

or these lines :

```
SpecificElementViewObservable.getInstance().setChanged();
SpecificElementViewObservable.getInstance().notifyObservers(new SpecificElementEvent(elementType, button));
```

or switch

```
SpecificElementViewObservable.getInstance().notifyObservers(new SpecificElementEvent(elementType, button));
```

to :

```
SpecificElementViewObservable.getInstance().notifyObservers();
```

Then each times my listener doesn't work (which is normal), but the css works again.

I also tried to remove the condition from the update method, so i can use notifyObservers() without parameters. Once again, my listener works, but not the CSS.

Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: It’s hard to tell looking at the code;  is your goal to make a series of buttons among which only one can be “selected”?

Comment: No my real goal is to change the content of the window according to the selected button. The css is just to see the selected button. Like a tab pane if you prefer but with button because I need them on different places (it's a list for tests but i'll probably place them in a different order later).

Comment: Have you considered a [TabPane](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TabPane.html)?

Comment: I was editing my answer while you answered. I considered tabPane but i'm not sure it's the best if i need to place this buttons in another order later.

Comment: If a TabPane doesn’t suit your needs, consider using [ToggleButtons](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.html) and a single ToggleGroup.  You may not need any additional styling at all, but if you do, it’s as easy as placing a rule set in your stylesheet with a `toggle-button:selected` selector.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced my buttons with toggleButtons and a ToggleGroup.
I still don't know what the problem was, but it's easier to do with it and it works.
I think the problem came from a mistake due to the need to handle the selected button myself and has been fixed by using the setSelected() and isSelected methods of toggleButtons.